# Banners continue to show up after user pay to remove? shared preferences java

Tags: java, android, admob

If user pay to remove banners I'd like to not show it.
I have this function when user pay:

```
void savepremium() {

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref01", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("plus", "2");
    editor.apply();

    String string = "Thanks";
    Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And this to add or not banners in main activity:

```
    //admob

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref01", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String plus = pref.getString("plus", "1");

    assert plus != null;
    if(plus.equals("1")) {
        AdView adView = new AdView(MainActivity.this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxx");

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    else {
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        if (mAdView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

and the xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Any ideas why some users are complaining about banners showing even after they pay to remove?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is probably not the problem, but if you want to set the visibility to **INVISIBLE** or **GONE**, you don't have to check if it is visible first, you can do without the `if` condition. Also, for future reference, there are functions like `getInt()`, `putInt()` and `getBoolean()`, `putBoolean()` in SharedPreferences. It would be slightly faster to use them compared to always using strings.

Comment: You are saying that some users are able to see the advertisement. You are only setting the values when `plus` equals `"1"`, so I'm thinking, for some reason, it still reads the value stored in `plus` as `1`. I don't think there's any problem here. Maybe when a user reinstalls the app but has already paid for everything, you'll obviously have a function to check if the user has paid and change the value if that were the case. Maybe there's something wrong with that function.

Comment: You should maintain that status from *back-end server* instead of managing it through *shared preferences* if user *uninstalls or clear data* it will be troubled for user.

Comment: How did you use savepremium() ? Show the code where you called that method. I think the problem lies there only. Also, in else part in your code, just write mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE); only. Just upload the code of BillingClient.

Comment: @MrudulTora it is called inside `public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, TransactionDetails details) {`

Comment: @RGS I don't know if your issue is resolved but if the problem is in BillingClient then have a look at this github link . https://github.com/mrudultora/Apk-Extractor-Android-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/toralabs/apkextractor/helperclasses/RemoveAds.java

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to remove the view once user purchases. This way all your views will be realign as well. Refresh your menu items as well...

```
if (getIsLicense() || BuildConfig.IsTestingON) {
                RemoveView();
}

private void RemoveView() {

        Log.d(TAG, "InsideRemoveView");
        if (adView != null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
            layout.removeView(adView);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        else
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();


    }
```